# Assigning DBNull to an integer type throwing an error when using with the ternary operator

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlparameter

I have a this piece of code below where I'm checking if a value in a certain field is blank ("") and if it is I want to set the value of the SqlParameter to NULL otherwise to the value from the field.

My original code was as below:

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@inID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = hiddenInID.Value.Trim()==""? DBNull.Value: hiddenInID.Value.Trim();
```

However the above code didn't work and it throws an error saying type of conditional element can't be determined because there is no implicit conversion between between DBNull and string.

So I had to change my code to this below:

```
if(hiddenInID.Value.Trim() == "")
{
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@inID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@inID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = hiddenInID.Value.Trim();
}
```

That worked. But why wouldn't it work the first way.  Is there a better way to do this with out an if else block?

Comment: Given you are passing a trimmed string to a parameter than is clearly an `int` - I'd suggest you investigate `int.TryParse`. But if you want to continue with your current approach, change `DBNull.Value:` to `(object)DBNull.Value:`.

Comment: @Z.R.T. That likely won't work. In the context of ADO.NET `null` and `DBNull.Value` have different meanings. `null` means 'no, I won't tell you the value of this parameter', **not** 'the value of this parameter is `NULL`'.

Comment: @Z.R.T. that didin't work.. i got an error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ..

Comment: `For parameters you can pass .net null.` That is not true @Z.R.T. Have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?view=netframework-4.7.2 . `Use null or do not set Value to use the default value for the parameter.` Try it for yourself. Create a stored proc with an int parameter with a default of 4. Calling it with `DBNull.Value` will call the stored proc with `NULL`. Calling it with `null` will call it with 4.

Comment: Yes. That is 100% consistent with what I said @Z.R.T. . By passing `null` you are using "use the default parameter (which happens to be `NULL`)". Which is not what most people think is what it is happening. `null`, in ADO.NET parameters, is to be used for one thing and one thing only - to specify that you explicitly **are not** providing the parameter value. _The fact that doing the wrong thing sometimes works, accidentally, doesn't make it a good idea. If you want to pass `NULL` as a parameter value then you must use `DBNull.Value` as per the link I provided above._